# getImageData in Firefox 3 causing NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR

Tags: javascript, firefox, getimagedata

I'm trying to develop an application that will use getImageData in javascript in Firefox 3, but I am getting a "`NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR`" on the getImageData call. The javascript and the image are both currently being served from by hard drive, which is apparently a security violation? When this is live they will both be served from the same domain, so it won't be a problem, but how can I develop in the meantime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try installing a local webserver such as Apache (on unix) or IIS (on Windows).  That will ultimately give you the best local test bench for web-related stuff, because as you have found out browsers treat files from the filesystem quite differently than content served from a webserver.

Comment: Good idea, I'll start running Apache (I'm on OS X).

Answer (score 5):

You can tell the browser to bug off.  The solution is better or worse depending on your circumstances.  I wrap it in a try so no security dialog will be presented if it's not an issue.

```
  var data;
  try {
    try {
      data = context.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh).data;
    } catch (e) {
      netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
      data = context.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh).data;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("unable to access image data: " + e);
  }
```

Comment: I'm playing with asp.net on one localhost port and editing css dragged in from another localhost port, and this is helping me get around, otherwise I couldn't access document.styleSheets[x].cssRules. big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, type "about:config" into your address bar. Then use the search field to search for "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy". Double click this to set it to "false".

Comment: This works, and is much easier than installing a server just to test some javascript locally.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using `getImageData` in FireFox 11.0 ... 
All my files and codes were on my server and there was nothing on my local computer.

I thought maybe this helps someone who has the same problem as me.

It looks like that Firefox treats

```
http://mySite.com
```

as a different domain from

```
http://www.mySite.com
```

So I used `.htaccess` to add `www.` when users don't type it in

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mySite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mySite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now it works fine and doesn't show `NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR` anymore.