# getimagedata not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, canvas

I got a problem with the HTML5 element getImageData()
I'm using wScratchPad for a scratch tool on a website and using the percentage function in wScratchPad to determine when to remove the overlay. It's working fine on IE9, Safari & Chrome. But it throws a SECURITY ERROR in Firefox.

I had the same problem in Chrome and IE9 too but fixed it by moving the JS, Images and HTML to the same server.

I know it throws an error if the domain of the JS and Canvas Image is not on the same domain so I checked the document.domain of both the image and the js. It looks like the JS as the 'document.domain = domain.com' and the image has document.domain = www.domain.com.

Could that be the problem? If so how can I fix it?
I already saw a way to override the browser to get a alert for the user confirmation of the script but seeing as this is a high profile website this is out of the question.

Below the code in wScratchPad which causes the error:

```
scratchPercentage: function($this)
{
    var hits = 0;
    var imageData = $this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,$this.canvas.width,$this.canvas.height)

    for(var i=0, ii=imageData.data.length; i<ii; i=i+4)
    {
        if(imageData.data[i] == 0 && imageData.data[i+1] == 0 && imageData.data[i+2] == 0 && imageData.data[i+3] == 0) hits++;
    }

    return (hits / $this.pixels) * 100;
},
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/366493/1438733

Comment: Unfortunately it throws and error in the console and does not help solve the problem in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your problem is that the page and image are not same-origin.

The way to fix it is to load the page from www.domain.com, just like the image, or to have your server send the appropriate CORS headers with the image.

I'm surprised you say it works in other browsers.  Did you perhaps load the page from www.domain.com in those?

Comment: yes I load the page trough www.domain but if I check the document.domain it's 'domain.com' the image and the page are on the same server and domain, the difference is that the document.domain of the image has 'www.domain.com' and not 'domain.com' unlike the page itself

Comment: @user1873378 Oh?  Does your script set `document.domain` to "domain.com" somewhere?  What version of Firefox are you testing?  Firefox 18 and later will ignore `document.domain` for the drawImage security check, but older versions do consider it...